# Can Java initialize Tahoma font for other than size 13 for Japanese unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, cjk

As described in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)
Not all fonts have glyphs for Japanese Unicode codepoints

(We're running Java 8)

The below test display shows text in *Latin, Japanese, Arabic, Korean and Russian* characters.
[image]

For **Japanese and Korean**, Java seems to import glyphs from another font into the Tahoma font for font-size 13 only.

Is there a way to let Java initialize Tahoma (or another font for that matter) by importing Japanese glyphs for multiple font-sizes?

Comment: Weird that it only works for one size. How did you create this test? JLabels or JTextFields, or is this JavaFX? Or were you using custom drawing e.g. in Swing using g.drawString()? In any case, in the absence of knowledge of what the reason is, maybe it helps to use custom drawing of the font and then changing the font size away from 13, and if that does not work, stick to 13 but change the *scaling* of the graphics object you're drawing with, that should keep the glyphs but change the effective size without crap like pixel repetition etc.

Comment: we used JTextField and used setFont() .No JavaFx